undefined reference to `init_ipc' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
i have this error, which i would say due to a wrong statement in the master file. i put the .h file on top. Compiling the files, through makefile, I get this error and I don't understand how to fix it
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start': (.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [Makefile:17: ipc] Error 1
master.c
#include "ipc.h"
void simulazione(char *config_file){

    signal(SIGINT, handle_termination);
    read_configuration_file(config_file);

    init_ipc();
    ...
}

ipc.c
void init_ipc() {
    key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65);
    shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(shared_data_t), 0666|IPC_CREAT);
    shared_data = (shared_data_t*) shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
    key_t sem_key = ftok("semfile", 75);
    semid = semget(sem_key, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, 1);
}

makefile
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wvla -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -D_GNU_SOURCE
CONFIG_FILE = config1.txt

all: ipc master 

ipc: ipc.o
    gcc ipc.o -o master

master: master.o
    gcc master.o -o master

ipc.o: src/ipc.c
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) src/ipc.c

master.o: src/master.c
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) src/master.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o ipc master ipc.o master.o 

run: master
    ./master $(CONFIG_FILE)


What does the makefile look like? Are you certain both .c files are being compiled and linked?

I added the makefile

The command gcc -c $(CFLAGS) ipc.o makes no sense. You can't build an executable program using the -c option.

And if you want a program that uses functions in another object file, you must link with that object file. Like gcc master.o ipc.o -o master

I corrected and the error changed

so in the makefile it makes no sense to define ipc, only ipc.o

Don't change "code" in your question, or ask about new errors or problems. If you get a new problem, then please ask a new question.

Yes, @MiusiZ, as presented in the question, ipc.c does not contain the source of a complete program, so it does not make sense to try to build one (ipc) from that source alone.  Of course, the same applies to master.c, but even more so -- not only is it missing a main() function, but it also calls init_ipc(), which is not defined in the same file.
